# Panda replace values in a column of lists

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a column based on another column, where each row is a list using a dictionary. I tried `replace` but this would only copy the column. I could loop over it using `iterrows` but the actual data set is very big, so an efficient (vectorized) solution would be appreciated

```
# what I have
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":[1,2,3], "col2":[["a"],["b","d"],"c"]})
translator= {"a":1,"b":2,"d":3}

# what I tried
# df["new"] = df.col2.replace(translator)
# df["new"] =  df.col2.map(translator) 

# what I need
df["new"] = [1,[2,3],np.NaN]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `apply` and comprehension:

```py
df['col2'].apply(lambda x: [translator.get(item, np.nan) for item in x])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
Out[66]: 
0       [1]
1    [2, 3]
2     [nan]
Name: col2, dtype: object
```

Comment: Good solution in my opinion.

Comment: @jezrael double vanilla python iteration? why would this be better than the native pandas methods?

Comment: @Umar.H - I think if working with list, vanilla python is better option.

Answer (score 2):

use explode and map

```
df['new'] = df['col2'].explode().map(translator).groupby(level=0).agg(list)

   col1    col2         new
0     1     [a]       [1.0]
1     2  [b, d]  [2.0, 3.0]
2     3       c       [nan]
```